# How to update/insert the status of one of the submitted suggestions in GridView by selecting a value from DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two tables in my database as following:

Suggestions Table: ID, Title, Description, StatusID... etc

SuggestionsStatus Table: ID, Status

I am using GridView to show the Suggestions and in the last column I put a DropDownList that for selecting the status for each Suggestion. Now, when I tried to update the Status of one of the submitted suggestions by selecting the status from the DropDownList, the value has been selected but it wasn't inserted to the Database (which means still I have NULL value in the StatusID column in the Suggestions Table) and I don't know why.

My ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" 
                        width="950px" CssClass="mGrid"
                        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" 
                        RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                        OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold = "true" ForeColor="Black" Height="20px"/> 
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
                    SortExpression="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" 
                    SortExpression="Username" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DivisionShortcut" HeaderText="Division" 
                    SortExpression="DivisionShortcut" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
                                          Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#006666" AppendDataBoundItems="false" 
                                          DataTextField="Status" DataValueField="ID" AutoPostBack="true" 
                                          OnDataBound="DropDownList_DataBound">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT     dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.ID, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Title, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Description, dbo.employee.Name, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username, 
                      dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut
FROM         dbo.employee INNER JOIN
                      dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Divisions ON dbo.employee.DivisionCode = dbo.Divisions.SapCode"
                      FilterExpression="[DivisionShortcut] like '{0}%'">

                      <FilterParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDivision" Name="DivisionShortcut" 
                                                 PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                    </FilterParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <%--For the DropDownList--%>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [SafetySuggestionsStatus]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My code-behind:

```
protected void DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    int suggestionStatus = int.Parse(ddl.SelectedValue);
    //For inserting the status in the database
    string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdbTest;Integrated Security=True";
    string insertCommand = "INSERT INTO SafetySuggestionsLog (StatusID) values(@StatusID)";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertCommand, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatusID", suggestionStatus);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I modified the DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged() as shown above but it gave me the following error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Title', table
>   'psspdbTest.dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog'; column does not allow nulls.
>   INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

**So how I can fix this problem to be able to update the status of one of the submitted Suggestions in the (GridView) in the database?**

Comment: Where is the code for your `INSERT` into the database?  The `GridView` control doesn't natively support inserts, you typically want to use a `DetailsView` or that.

Answer (score 2):

I think your operation has to be done when the drop down list value changes right?
 For that you have to use the `OnSelectedIndexChanged`method. When the value in the drop down changes, this method fires. Here you can write your code.

I think you didnt mention your database insert logic here.
in asp drop down list please add this

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DBList" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="226px"  OnSelectedIndexChanged ="DBList_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Now write in the .cs file

```
protected void DBList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// inserting into database code here
}
```

Find these links [link1](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/tutorials/article.php/c19375) [link2](http://forums.asp.net/t/1436992.aspx/1)

Comment: firstly, thanks for your help. Secondly, just for your information, the DropDownList is inside the GridView, so the selected value should be inserted to the GridView. I tried to do that but I failed and I don't know why. Could you please have a look at my updated code above?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest that you are trying to insert into table 
that have for example 4 columns 
ID, Title, Description, StatusID
you are try to insert the statusid only with ignoring all others column and error say that title column not allow null 
if you want to allow it to accept null
so from table design set allow null true to title column